# Check radio button id when there're two radio groups

Tags: java, android, radio-button

I am a beginner in Android programming, and trying to create a simple program that converts inches to feet, and US dollars to Japanese Yen. I have the following two radio groups in my main_activity.xml file:

```
 <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/distanceInput"
        android:layout_below="@+id/distanceInput"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/inch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:checked="true"
            android:onClick="handleClickOne"
            android:text="Inches" />

        <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/foot"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/currencyInput"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:onClick="handleClickOne"
        android:text="Feet" />

    </RadioGroup>

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/currencyInput"
        android:layout_below="@+id/currencyInput"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/japan"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioGroup2"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="JPY" 
            android:onClick="handleClickTwo"
            />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/usdollar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/euro"
            android:layout_below="@+id/euro"
            android:text="US Dollars" 
            android:onClick="handleClickTwo"
            />
    </RadioGroup>
```

This following code is for my handleClickOne() method that checks which radio button is selected between Inches and Feet, but the switch-case loop always falls on the default case - I wonder why:

```
public void handleClickOne(View view) {
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");


    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    EditText distance = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.distanceInput);
    double distanceInput = parseStringToDouble(distance.getText().toString());

    switch(view.getId()) { 
    case R.id.foot:
        // convert inches to feet
        if (checked) {
            distance.setText(df.format(inchToFoot(distanceInput)));
        }
        break;

    case R.id.inch:
        //convert feet to inches
        if (checked) {
            distance.setText(df.format(footToInch(distanceInput)));
        }
        break;

    default:  
        distance.setText("000");
        break;
    }
}
```

My question is whether I need to select a radio button in a radio group? and if so how?

Comment: Is the click perhaps being registered on the RadioGroup (id radioGroup1) instead of the child views?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you, but I have this line in my radio button: android:onClick="handleClickOne", does this mean I registered the click handler on the radio button?

Comment: Add a Log statement (or breakpoint) in your default case to check the id of the view that's being passed in. This should help figure out why the default case is being hit, rather than the R.id.foot or R.id.inch cases.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
RadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener
```

rather than `onclick` to see which radio button is set. I dont think onclick works reliably for radiobutton

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do, but the following works for now:

Because I know which click handler method works for which radio group, so in each of my click handler methods (in this case `handleClickOne()`), I get the radioGroup object first:

```
RadioGroup radioGroup1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
```

then do my switch-case in this way:

```
switch(radioGroup1.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) { 
        case R.id.foot:
        // convert inches to feet
        if (checked) {
            distance.setText(df.format(inchToFoot(distanceInput)));
        }
        break;

    case R.id.inch:
        //convert feet to inches
        if (checked) {
            distance.setText(df.format(footToInch(distanceInput)));
        }
        break;

    default:
            distance.setText("error");
            break;
}
```

It works for now, but I'm still interested in learning the best practice. Thanks to all!